# c expected expression before {aStructName}

Tags: c, syntax

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STORAGESIZE 5
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 2

typedef struct{
      char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
      char feild1;
      char feild2;
  } strt;
  static strt storage[5];

main(){
 unsigned char *stp=(unsigned char*)&strt;
 unsigned char*stp_end=(unsigned char*)(&strt+STORAGESIZE);
 int i;

 for(i=0;stp!=stp_end;stp++,i++)
   printf("byte%d: %x\n",i,*stp);

}
```

I am trying to confirm that all of a structure declared as static will be initialized to 0 except possibly the padding portions of it.
and I got errors when attempting to compile the above: statictable.c:

```
In function 'main':
statictable.c:13:38: error: expected expression before 'strt'
statictable.c:14:42: error: expected expression before 'strt'
```

What could possibly be wrong in an assignment of a casted pointer to another pointer.Although I know this could turn out to be rudimentary.

Comment: Always specify the return type (`int`) for `main()`; C99 (and C11) require it.  On the whole, it is best to return a value (0 for success) from the program, though C99 does allow you to omit it and it then returns zero — but C89 does not allow you to omit the return value.  You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line:

```
unsigned char *stp=(unsigned char*)&strt;
```

You give pointer to `strt` which is a type, not a variable. iIt's like `&int` (invalid as well :) ), you shuold probably do:

```
unsigned char *stp=(unsigned char*)storage;
```

And same for the next line.

Comment: You probably don't need the `&` before the array name.  It doesn't matter in the first line, but it surely does in the second!

Answer (score 1):

In these two lines:

```
unsigned char *stp=(unsigned char*)&strt;
unsigned char*stp_end=(unsigned char*)(&strt+STORAGESIZE);
```

You're trying to take the address of the *type*: `strt`. You want the address of your `strt` array: `storage`.

Comment: Probably not the address of the array; just the name of the array.  It doesn't matter too much in the first line; it does matter (a lot) in the second line.